# Where can I find good tutorials for an OS X newbie?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac, software-recommendation, macbook-pro

I am using Mac OSX Snow Leopard.
Now, I am giving my MacBook to my younger brother, who is quite new to OS X and Unix. He is using Windows for thelast 8 months, and is quite familiar with it.

I need your guidance in finding Video Tutorials, that I can give to him so he can learn on his own about different things.

Please suggest some video tutorials from any provider, be it Lynda or Total Training. Even ebooks and books titles are welcome.

Answer (score 10):

Apple has some great short videos on different aspects of using a mac and OS X including coming from windows, video, music, photos, web and iWork and its all over at their '*Find Out How*' website.

http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/

Answer (score 2):

As a newer Mac user myself I can highly recommend Screencasts Online (ref.) http://www.screencastsonline.com produced by Don McAllister.

Your initial subscription is for 3 months because you can download or view online the complete library of shows. The ongoing monthly subscription is very reasonable and you can stop and resume the subscription as the need arises.

The quality is very high both in terms of production value and content.  He produces a weekly episode with a mix of topics for both new users and fairly advanced enthusiasts.

Some of the episodes are free with the rest being members only.  The free shows can be downloaded as an iTunes podcast (search for "screencasts online free version" in the iTunes store).  This will give you an indication of the content and quality of production.

For a reach over to the bookshelf, find a specific answer situation I recommend David Pogue's "Mac OSX Snow Leopard" from "The Missing Manual" series. (ref.) http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596153298.do.   He writes with clarity, thoroughness and humor.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has [an entire area](http://www.apple.com/why-mac/) on it's website dedicated to people switching from Windows to Mac.